# Android movie manager

Tags: gratis, android, media-manager

So I'm looking for an Android app that allows me to manage/sort/filter/play my videos and movie located on my SD card.

- it should support tagging
- it should support custom tags
- it should look pretty
- it should let me choose my own player
- customization is a must

Comment: Are you talking about movies in terms of "video files" stored on the device – or rather just "metadata" on movies? In the latter case: manually entered? Or retrieved from a different source? Should the app be able to retrieve metadata from other sources (e.g. IMDb) – and are there any preferences towards the source and the details?

Comment: Videos from any source. Amateur, pro or cinema

Comment: Yes! Now it's clear, thanks a lot. I rarely deal with videos on my Android devices, so I have no candidate I could tell; but while waiting for a matching recommendation, you might wish to take a look into my list of [Video-Players](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_video_player). Like with MP3-Players, I would imagine one of them also offering "organization features" like the ones you're looking for. For a plain organizer, [Galleries](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_galleries) might have the fitting candidates.

Comment: Alas I don't see anyone that supports tags Thanks anyawy!

Comment: You're welcome. There are several gallery apps supporting tags, annotations, and more – and most also support videos. The overlap might be small, though, as often tags are stored in Exif data – and I'm not sure what video formats might support something similar. But now that it's clear what you're after, hopefully some answers turn up soon. I keep my fingers crossed!

Comment: What is the number after the @?

Comment: As this is not a discussion forum, I'd suggest better to clear that in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12851/software-recommendations) (you've got the required rep for that). As for this detail: Try the blue question mark in the upper-right corner of the page, help pages explain things like this ;) Hint: `rating@votes [num-of-permissions]`.

Comment: Sorry. monte Image viewer looks good but it's not free :/. Perhaps I should develop such app